# Start another application in my own layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i'm building an application and need a layout that shows another application, there is any way to open the another app from in my own application?
(i don't want an intent to open the normal  app, I want to open it from in my application)

I need that because my layout have some good animation(for example, fade in and out every 20 sec)

for example -

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start another application within your application. this is now how android works. The only option you have is to start the application using an intent.

From Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

> The Android Application Sandbox, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.